# Working with multiple user tables in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to Laravel, and currently I am developing a job website project using Laravel 5. In the website, in addition to the Admin user, I have three types of users- jobseeker, employer, and training provider, which I want to seperate the three tables because each of them store different information. Plus, each of them should go to certain allowed user logged in area. For example, logged job seeker can only work on their allowed area, and employer and training provider can do the same thing.

Could you advise me how to manage authentication for each tables?

Best Regards,
Naren

Answer (score 1):

The best way to manage this in Laravel is use a plugin. Try this: [Laravel ACL](https://github.com/kodeine/laravel-acl)

It uses following table to manage role based access for entire application:

1. users
2. role_user
3. roles
4. permissions
5. permission_role
6. permission_user

By using this module you can manage role wise as well as individual person permission also.

Comment: Thank you for the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can apply the following stuffs from Laravel 5.2+,

- Use multi [authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication). So each type of user has its own model: **JobSeeker, Employer, TrainingProvider**. They will have their own `Guard` in middleware for authentication.
- Routes are protected via [middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/middleware). Some routes are permitted to all, some are personal...
- Since each role might have same or different access to some type of actions, ex. all have access the **JobSeeker** profile (to view), but only **JobSeeker** can edit the profile. Use the [Laravel Policy](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authorization#policies).